# why does web api call returns html page after iis deployment

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am calling web api method from angularjs controller as follows.

```
$http.get('../api/Home/AppLogin').then(function (response) {
    alert(response.data);
, function (error) {
    alert('Error: ' + error.message);
})
```

I am using angularJs routing as follows:

```
var cioTrack = angular.module('CIOTrack', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']);
//Define Routing for the application
cioTrack.config(
function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'Index.html',
            controller: 'IndexController'
        }).
        when('/Notify', {
            templateUrl: 'Views/Notify.html',
            controller: 'NotifyController'
        }).
        when('/Report', {
            templateUrl: 'Views/Report.html',
            controller: 'ReportController'
        })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

In config I have following rules:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="rewriteRule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Web api controller method:

```
[Route("api/Home/AppLogin")]
[HttpGet]
public string AppLogin()
    {
        return "some string";
    }
```

This is working fine when I run from visual studio. but api call returns complete html after I deploy the code on web server (IIS).

output of success function if I run from Visual Studio: I get alert with string "some string"

output of success function if I run after deployment on IIS web server is I get complete page html as message.

IIS version is 7.5
I have installed URL rewrite on the IIS web server.

Please tell me what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding one more condition in rewrite rule. Sharing it for others.

```
<add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="/API/" />
```